# Scatter plot colors corresponding to a value

Tags: python, matplotlib, colormap

In all the colormap posts I have not found this answer, or maybe did not understand it.

I want to make a scatter plot with colors.

I have a list B:

```
[1.29,
 1.27,
 1.46,
 0.91,
 0.56,
 0.99,
 1.00,
 0.37,
 1.24,
 1.23]
```

I will just use a stupid example, if you do:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
from math import sin

x=range(10)
y=[sin(i) for i in x]
colors=np.linspace(0,1,10)

plt.scatter(x,y,c=colors,cmap=cm.jet)
```

You get points with different colors, nice.
[image]

BUT ! I do not want to only get nicely colored points ! I want the points to be colored according to the "intensity" of the values in B.

Here is my stupid attempt:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
from math import sin

x=range(10)
y=[sin(i) for i in x]
#colors=np.linspace(0,1,10)
B=[1.29,1.27,1.46,0.91,0.56,0.99,1.00,0.37,1.24,1.23]

plt.scatter(x,y,c=B,cmap=cm.jet)
```

You get points colored according to the intensity of the values in B, very nice:
[image]

BUT !! I would like to change the "scale" of colors to have deep blue at 0 and deep red at 2. In which case the third point (associated with `B[2]=1.46`) should be orange and not deep red ! How should I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to set the minimum and maximum colour manually using vmin and vmax arguments. For your case, this is,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
from math import sin

x=range(10)
y=[sin(i) for i in x]
#colors=np.linspace(0,1,10)
B=[1.29,1.27,1.46,0.91,0.56,0.99,1.00,0.37,1.24,1.23]

cs = plt.scatter(x,y,c=B,cmap=cm.jet,vmin=0.,vmax=2.)
plt.colorbar(cs)
plt.show()
```